# Autocorrelation fitting algorithm

Tags: variance, autocorrelation, curve-fitting, cross-correlation, spectral-analysis

I am currently working on an autocorrelation fitting algorithm, similar to this for a gaussian spectral signal

[image]

I would like to calculate parameters such as velocity and spectrum width using a finite length data set (16 or 32 samples), and to use a weighting scale based on the variance of each lag to obtain the parameters.  However, I am not sure how to calculate variances of each lag to obtain fitting weights, though there is something like this on  stackexchange [Variance of a sample covariance for normal variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287144/variance-of-a-sample-covariance-for-normal-variables), but I do not understand how it may fit with my case.  Is there a derivation available for a an engineer like me?  Thanks.